# Best way to do real-time per-pixel filtering with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, glsl

I have an image that needs to be filtered and then displayed on the screen.  Below is a simplified example of what I want to do:

[image: Per-Pixel Filtering Scheme]

The left image is the screen-buffer as it would be displayed on the screen.
The middle is a filter that should be applied to the screen buffer.
The right image is the screen buffer as it should be displayed to the screen.

I am wondering what the best method of achieving this within the context of OpenGL would be.

- Fragment Shader?
- Modify the pixels one-by-one?

The final version of this code will be applied to a screen that is constantly changing and needs to be per-pixel filtered no matter what the "original" screen-buffer shows.

Edit, Concerns about fragment shader:
  - The fragment shader isn't guaranteed to give fragments of size 1x1, so how would I can't say "ModifiedImage[x][y].red += Filter[x][y].red" Within the fragment shader

Comment: Yes... Fragment Shader...

Comment: Render to FBO, then draw a fullscreen quad with using both the FBO contents and your filter in the fragment shader?

Comment: @Vallentin, can you expand on how you would do this with a fragment shader?  See my "edit".

Answer (score 1):

You could blend the images together using OpenGL's blending functions (glBlendFunc, glEnable( GL_BLEND ) etc.)

Comment: This sounds good!  What would I blend with?  Can I create an NxN matrix of r/g/b/ values and have openGL automatically blend with them?

Comment: @JonSandness: You blend the output of your fragment shader (source) with the pixel already in the framebuffer (destination). You can only blend 1 fragment at a time, so if you need to know adjacent pixels to compute the value of a single pixel you are going to need to use an image processing kernel and an FBO.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I don't need to know adjacent pixels, but I have an NxN matrix of RGB values that need to be applied to the image.

I'd be fine using a fragment shader if I was able to know "What pixel does this fragmen correspond to?"  Then I could look up the corresponding filter in the NxN matrix and apply it to that filter.

Comment: @JonSandness: If you can make this `NxN` matrix into something more generic like a texture, then it is a good use-case for fragment shaders. You can stretch that texture over a tile on screen, do something in the fragment shader and then blend.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman okay I played around with the fragment shader and I think this will work! Is there a way for me to convert from an NxN matrix (2d Array of RGB values) to a GL_TEXTURE_TD?

Comment: You have to *linearize* the 2D array (create a single array with size `N*N*3` that appends each row of the matrix), and then you can pass it to `glTexImage2D (...)` as a single block of bytes.